# How do I accept blanks in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program which calculates the result of exams by taking in the number of marks obtained in each subject. It is almost done but I'm encountering an error that is, if the user just presses enter instead of entering a value, the application wont proceed. Also is there any way to shortening this code?

```
Console.WriteLine("Danyal's result calculator for students of class IX. Enter the marks requested, if not applicable leave blank and press enter :)");
Console.Write("Enter your Urdu marks: ");
int urdu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your Maths marks: ");
int maths = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your English Literature marks: ");
int lit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your Biology marks: ");
int bio = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your Chemistry marks: ");
int chem = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your Islamiat marks: ");
int isl = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your Physics marks: ");
int physics = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your Computer marks: ");
int comp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your English Language marks: ");
int lang = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter your Pakistan Studies marks: ");
int pst = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


int total = urdu + maths + lit + lang + bio + chem + physics + isl + comp + pst;
Console.WriteLine("Your total marks are {0} out of 1000", total);
float percentage = total * 100 / 1000;
Console.WriteLine("Your percentage is: {0}%",percentage);
Console.WriteLine("Note: the percentage has been rounded off. Please share this program with other classmates, also I am open to suggestions for creating more helpful programs.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Same as if they enter anything thats not a number?  Create a method that prompts & calls int.TryParse() within a loop

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you would want to do in case the user leaves it blank, or enters an invalid value, but you could do something like this.

```
        Dictionary<string,int> grades = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            { "Urdu", 0 },
            { "Maths", 0 },
            { "English", 0 },
            { "Biology", 0 },
            { "Chemistry", 0 },
            { "Islamiat", 0 },
            { "Physics", 0 },
            { "Computer", 0 },
            { "English Language", 0 },
            { "Pakistan Studies", 0 },
        };

        foreach (string grade in grades.Keys.ToArray())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enter your {0} marks: ", grade));
            int mark;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mark))
                grades[grade] = mark;
        }
        int total = grades.Sum((g) => g.Value);
```

In this example, if bad input is used the grade will default to 0.  If you wanted to you could change the if try parse to a loop and request a good value until one is entered as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clear case of not adhering to the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle. You are repeating operations that are essentially the same, don't do that. Refactor the code so that common patterns or behaviors are solved in one single place.

How would you do that here?

1. Create a method that prompts the user to enter certain information. What does the user need? A descriptive message of what he has to do. What does the user need to do? Enter a valid input. Ok, with that in mind, the following prototype of a method seems like a good starting point:

   ```
   private static int GetUserInput(string message) { ... }
   ```
2. Hmmm...enter a valid input. This means we need some sort of validation, so again let's think of how we can solve this:

   ```
   private static int ValidateUserInput(string input) { ... }
   ```

   Is this good enough? Well...no quite. What happens if the user enters an incorrect number? There is no convenient way of conveying that the input is not valid to the caller. We could return -1, or we could throw an exception, but both seem offish.

   The best solution would be to return two values; one telling us if the input is valid and another telling us what the input is. In c# this isn't very striaghtforward (at least until c# 7 comes along). The way to do it is using `out` arguments:

   ```
   private static bool ValidateUserInput(string message, out int input) { ... }
   ```

   Now this method serves our purpose perfectly. The return value tells us if the input is valid and the `out` argument `input` gives us the validated value (or we simply ignore it if the validation failed).
3. Why are you creating an `int` variable for each mark if you essentially only want sums and averages? Lets create a `List<int>` where we store all the marks.

   Another option, if you want to keep track of what mark corresponds to what subject, would be to use a `Dictionary<string, key>` where the key would be the subject name and the value its corresponding mark. But lets use `List<int>` for now.

With all that in mind we can build up our solution:

```
public static void ComputeMarksSummary()
{
     var marks = new List<int>();

     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your Urdu marks: "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your Maths marks: : "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your English Literature marks: "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your Biology marks: "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your Chemistry marks: "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your Islamiat marks: "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your Computer marks: "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your English language marks: "));
     marks.Add(GetUserInput("Enter your Pakistan studies marks: "));

     var total = marks.Sum();
     Console.WriteLine("Your total marks are {0} out of 1000", total);
     Console.WriteLine("Your percentage is: {0}%", total/10.0); //note the 10.0 to force double division, not integer division where 44/10 would be 4 not 4.4
     Console.WriteLine("Note: the percentage has been rounded off. Please share this program with other classmates, also I am open to suggestions for creating more helpful programs.");
     //WRONG! Percentage is not rounded off, its truncated: 9/10 is 0 in integer division.
     Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int GetUserInput(string message)
{
     int mark;

     while (true)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(message);
          var input = Console.ReadLine();

          if (!ValidateUserInput(input, out mark))
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please try again.");
          }
          else
          {
               return mark;
          }
     }
}

private static bool ValidateUserInput(string message, out int input)
{ 
    //left as an excerice. Hint: look into int.TryParse(...);
    //here you could decide if a blank input should be valid and parsed as zero. 
}
```

Wow, now that seems a lot cleaner....but hey, we can still do a little bit better. Whats up with all those `marks.Add(....)`? Can't we refactor the code some more? Well yes, we are essentially asking always the same thing, only the subject name changes. How about we do something like this:

```
public static void ComputeMarksSummary(IEnumerable<string> subjectNames)
{
     var marks = new List<int>();

     foreach (var subject in sujectNames)
     {
         marks.Add(GetUserInput(string.Format("Enter your {0} marks: ", subject)));
     }

     var total = marks.Sum();
     Console.WriteLine("Your total marks are {0} out of 1000", total);
     Console.WriteLine("Your percentage is: {0}%", total/10.0); //note the 10.0 to force double division, not integer division where 44/10 would be 4 not 4.4
     Console.WriteLine("Note: the percentage has been rounded off. Please share this program with other classmates, also I am open to suggestions for creating more helpful programs.");
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
ComputeMarksSummary(new string[] { "Urdu", "Maths", ... );
```

Doesn't that seem so much cleaner?

Comment: Woah! thats a lot to absorb in. U see im a total newbie just getting started and i used my imagination. Im learning from the MS Virtual Academy. Well thanks a lot! for writing all that down and explaining. It has helped and ive come to know of the different helper methods like .sum and sorry for using the wrong terminology that rounded off thing.

Comment: @DanyalAhmedKhan don't despair! I understand that for a beginner it might seem a little daunting but at the end of the day it's just applying logic and thinking of how to code in a more clear and maintainable way...remember most of the time of a professional coder is not spent writing code, it's spent reviewing someone others. Imagine tomorrow you have to improve your code adding two new subjects and removing one deprecated one. Think about how you'd need to change your code and how you'd need to change the final version of my answer. Make your future life, and others, easier!

Comment: Im encountering another problem! @InBetween http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314181/how-to-create-an-age-calculator-that-tells-the-age-in-hours-days-and-years Hope ull help me there too