# How to create an Age calculator that tells the age in hours, days and years?

Tags: c#

Another newbie question. I am trying to create an age calculator that takes the users age and then subtracts it from the current date and display it to the user.
I've got the basic idea. 
Here is my example code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Age_Calculator
    {
         class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime Current = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your birth date: ");
            string myBirthDate = Console.ReadLine();
            //ive got the date from the user, now how do i subtract  the current date from the date of birth?
            string myAge = //here the result is stored
                           //then displayed as hours
                           //then displayed as days
                           //finally as years
                           //will use replacement code i think
            Console.WriteLine(myAge);

            //Ive got the idea but due to lack of knowledge i cant make this application



        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Take todays date and subtract the date of birth, it should give a timespan object which you can use to get the info you need from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime Current = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your birth date: ");
            string myBirthDate = Console.ReadLine();
            var birthDate = DateTime.Parse(myBirthDate);

           TimeSpan myAge = Current - birthDate;
           Console.WriteLine($"Hours: {myAge.TotalHours}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Days: {myAge.TotalDays}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Years: {Current.Year - birthDate.Year}");

           Console.WriteLine(myAge);
        }
```

Comment: that works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot! Could u give me some explanation about the .Parse? and why use a var in birthDate? why not a string?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()` is a framework method that returns a `DateTime` object given a valid-ish string (e.g. 12.12.2018 or 12/12/2018 or similar). It can't be a string as c# is strongly typed. Also, it is a good practice to use `var` keyword when the right part of the assignment operator is deterministic. If the answer works for you, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

void getAge(int,int,int);
int main(){
    int mm,dd,yr;
    cout<<"                                     WELCOME TO AGE CALCULATOR\n";
    cout<<"                                     _________________________"<<endl;
    cout<<"ENTER YOUR DOB IN DD/MM/YR\n";
    cin>>dd>>mm>>yr;
    getAge(dd,mm,yr);
    
    return 0;
}

void getAge(int dd,int mm,int yr){

    yr=yr-1900;
    mm=mm-1;

    time_t t=time(NULL);
    struct tm* timeStruct = localtime(&t);
    cout<<abs(dd-(timeStruct->tm_mday))<<"-"<<abs(mm-(timeStruct->tm_mon))<<yr-(timeStruct->tm_year)<<endl;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post answer just with code. Please add some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP. Please also use the same programming language as it is used in the question.